# PHP Sort multi Array by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I want to know how can I sort this in PHP in base of "**leaguePoints**" and then in "**wins**"

```
<?php
            foreach ($league as $leaguesList)
            {
                if ($leaguesList->queue == "RANKED_SOLO_5x5")
                {
                    foreach ($leaguesList as $list)
                    {
                       if ($list->division == $leagueSummoner->division){
                           $array[] = $list;
                       }
                    }
                }
            }

    var_dump($array);
```

**Result:** http://pastebin.com/QkKU7W0k

I'm trying to port this from Java, which I do in this way:

```
    public void setRankList(List<LeagueSummonerLeagueStats> _rankList) {

    rankList = _rankList;
    Collections.sort(rankList, new Comparator() {

        public int compare(Object match1Obj, Object match2Obj) {

            LeagueSummonerLeagueStats league1 = (LeagueSummonerLeagueStats) match1Obj;

            LeagueSummonerLeagueStats league2 = (LeagueSummonerLeagueStats) match2Obj;

            int i = Integer.compare(league2.getLeaguePoints(), league1.getLeaguePoints());

            if (i != 0)
                return i;

            i = Integer.compare(league2.getWins(), league1.getWins());

            if (i != 0)
                return i;

            return -1;
        }
    });
    }
```

Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What you'll need to do in PHP, is exactly what you see being done in Java: you must define a sort-comparison function.  (See PHP's documentation.)  This function will return a value that is less than, equal to, or greater than zero, depending on the order between the two variables provided to it by the sort-engine.  "I'm not a code-writing service," but the implementation should be clear.

Comment: P.S. I wonder if there might be a *bug* in that Java routine ... I never see how it could return *zero!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like to normally provide solutions, but you just needed to port it to another language.

Basically, you want to write a bubblesort callback, which will first compare two records wins properties, then if they are equal, fall back to the league points property. Something like

```
$data = [
    [
        'wins' => 10,
        'leaguePoints' => 10,
    ],
    [
        'wins' => 10,
        'leaguePoints' => 20,
    ],
    [
        'wins' => 20,
        'leaguePoints' => 10,
    ],    
    [
        'wins' => 10,
        'leaguePoints' => 10,
    ],
];

usort($data, function($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['wins'] === $b['wins']) {
        if ($a['leaguePoints'] === $b['leaguePoints']) {
            return 0;
        }

        return ($a['leaguePoints'] > $b['leaguePoints']) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    return ($a['wins'] > $b['wins']) ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) like so:

```
function myCompare($a, $b) {
    // comparison code here
}

usort($mydata, 'myCompare');
```

or with an anonymous function:

```
usort($mydata, function($a, $b){ /* ... */ });
```

or you can feed in any [Callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) that accepts two arguments and returns a negative number, zero, or positive number.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I have the indexes correct.

```
foreach($league as $leaguesList){

  foreach ($leaguesList as $key => $list){

    $leaguePoints = [$key] ["info"]["leaguePoints"];
    $wins = [$key] ["info"]["info"]["wins"];
    $sort = $leaguePoints *= 100 + $wins;
    $sorted[$sort] = $list;

  }
}
ksort($sorted);
```